# Apply where clause within count in sql

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    Rooms.Building, 
    Count(Rooms.Room) AS TotalApartments, 
    Count(Rooms.Room) AS ApartmentsOccupied
FROM 
    Rooms
WHERE 
    (((Rooms.AssetType) <> 'LC')) 
GROUP BY 
    Rooms.Building;
```

I want to count `Rooms.Room` Where `Rooms.Occupied = True` (`ApartmentsOccupied`) but when I put this clause into my sql it also applies the where to the TotalApartments column

Comment: `Count(case Rooms.Room when true then 1 end) AS ApartmentsOccupied`. Depends of course on what "sql" is "sql".

Comment: Instead of a where, try using a having COUNT(Rooms.ROOM) > 0 or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can move some logic into CASE statements to do conditional summarization:

```
SELECT
    Rooms.Building,
    Count(Rooms.Room) AS TotalApartments,
    Sum(CASE WHEN Rooms.Occupied = True THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ApartmentsOccupied
FROM 
    Rooms
WHERE 
    (((Rooms.AssetType) <> 'LC')) 
GROUP BY 
    Rooms.Building;
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head, but you might need to change that count to a SUM as well:

```
Sum(1) AS TotalApartments
```

And alternately, in some sql dialects the 'True' value is 1, so you could get away with something like this for the occupied count:

```
Sum(Rooms.Occupied) AS ApartmentsOccupied
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
SELECT 
    Building, 
    Count(Room) AS TotalApartments, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Occupied = True THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ApartmentsOccupied
FROM 
    Rooms
WHERE 
    AssetType <> 'LC' 
GROUP BY 
    Building;
```